# How to return additionally field from entity which is not a column in database?

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, typeorm

I have an entity with several field with annotation `@Column` like below:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  lastName: string;
}
```

when after save I return saved object then he return me only this three field, but i want to return another one field: `fullName` but i do not want to save  it in database

so, i try add this field in eneity:

```
fullName: string;
```

but when I map on this field my `text` and return this object, then return me all but not return me my fullName, can someone tell me how to return additionally field from entity which is not a column in database?

Answer (score 2):

You could add this part to your entity:

```
fullName: string; // just define a property to use it in afterLoad method

@AfterLoad() // this method will be called on each entity query
afterLoad() {
    this.fullName = `${this. firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}
```

Comment: hmmm but what if I want to set my fullName not in entity but in service in different class?

Comment: @ertyjdjgdfgj you could try to add select like this one _(example for query-builder)_: `.select(['CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) as fullName'])`, but I'm not sure that it would work in a proper way

Answer (score 0):

You could create a type representing your final data like:

```
type CustomUser = {
   id: number;
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   fullName: string;
}
```

After that, make your query to return this type

```
  return getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
            .select('user.id', 'id')
            .select('user.firstName', 'firstName')
            .addSelect('user.lastName', 'lastName')
            .addSelect('CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName', 'fullName')      
            .getRawMany();

// getRawMany() if you want to fetch many records or getRawOne()
```

If you need just a fullName column for all users, you could try:

```
const { fullName } = await getManager()
        .createQueryBuilder(User, 'user').select('CONCAT(firstName, ' ', 
        lastName', 'fullName').getRawMany();
return fullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  lastName: string;

 @Expose()
  public get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

When doing the above, the database does not store the fullName value in a column. Instead, it is computed every time on the fly when accessed.